# React this.props is an empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that contains a list based on an array

```
render: function () {
     var navItems = ['X', "Y", 'Z']
     var self = this;
     var NAV_ITEMS = navItems.map(function(item, i){
         return <li item={item} key={i} onMouseOver={self.handleMouseEnter}> {item}{i} </li>
     });
    return( <div> {NAV_ITEMS} </div> )
}
```

At this point, shouldn't each of these elements have the prop equivalent to the letter passed in via the array? The next part, the mouseEnter I would like to `console.log(this.props)`, but it shows up as an empty object.

Here is my handleMouseEnter function:

```
handleMouseEnter: function(){
    console.log("Mouse Over!" this.props)
},

=> {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be passing props to react components not html elements. If you were instead returning a react component that rendered as a list component you could access the prop.

As is you could bind the property to a function with

```
onMouseOver={self.handleMouseEnter.bind(this, item}
```

Or create a react component like

```
var NavItem = React.createClass({
    handleMouseEnter: function(){
        //You will see item here
        console.log("Mouse Over!" this.props)
    },
    render(): function(){
        return <li onMouseOver={self.handleMouseEnter}> {item}{i} </li>
    }
}
```

And in your loop go

```
var items = navItems.map(function(item, i){
    return <NavItem item={this.props.item} key={i} />
});
```

Comment: Actually though, item is undefined if I'm not referencing the index in the array. So in the NavItem component, {item} is undefined.

Comment: Pretty key to have that part be the '{this.props.item}' not {item}.

Comment: Yeah edited. Sorry in your explanation it sounded like you already knew it had to access props from this.props. The important thing in your code wasn't whether you were lacking this.props or not but that you were passing react props to a html element.